# How to execute stored procedure while batching?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to execute the stored procedure by passing parameter values from a table for a batch size of 100. Once the stored procedure call is made for first batch of 100, move on to next batch of 100 and repeat till all the rows in the table are done. The table has a column which will get updated making sure that same row doesn't get picked up when i do

```
select top (batch_size) * 
from table
```

I question is more about how to implement batching for the stored procedure call.

EDIT:  Added OP's comment:

Example, table1 below has 1000 rows. my first batch is for 500 rows. Making one stored procedure call for each row.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    id INT IDENTITY, 
    col1 VARCHAR(100), 
    status VARCHAR(50)
) 

DECLARE @batch_size INT 
SET @batch_size = 5 

INSERT INTO table2 
    SELECT TOP(500) col1 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE status IS NULL 
    ORDER BY id 

SELECT TOP(1) 
    @id = id, @col1 = col1, @col2 = col2 
FROM table2 
ORDER BY id 

WHILE @@rowcount > 0  
BEGIN 
     EXEC SP param1 = col1, param2 = col2 

     UPDATE table1 
     SET status = 'closed' 

     SELECT TOP(1) @id = id, @col1 = col1, @col2 = col2 
     FROM table2 
     WHERE id > @id 
     ORDER BY id 
END
```

Comment: Can you post some ddl, sample data, proc code and what you are trying to do? Without those details we are just guessing.

Comment: What do you mean by " execute the SP by passing parameter values from a table for a batch size of 100"?    Your stored procedure takes 100 parameter values at once?

Comment: --Example, table1 below has 1000 rows. my first batch is for 500 rows. making one SP call for each row. 
CREATE TABLE table1
(id INT IDENTITY,
 col1 VARCHAR(100),
 status VARCHAR(50))

DECLARE @batch_size INT
SET @batch_size=5

INSERT INTO table2
SELECT TOP(500) col1 FROM table1 WHERE status IS NULL ORDER BY id

SELECT TOP(1) @id=id @col1=col1,@col2= col2 FROM table2 ORDER BY id

WHILE @@rowcount >0
BEGIN
   EXEC SP param1=col1, param2=col2

   UPDATE table1 SET status='closed'

   SELECT TOP(1) @id=id @col1=col1,@col2= col2 FROM table2 
   WHERE id >@id
   ORDER BY id 

END

Comment: After first 500 rows are done. how do I select next 500 rows?

Comment: remember last id and filter

Comment: If you're making one SP call for each row, why do it in batches at all?   Do you think you're going to get some performance benefit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying you're going about this the best way, but to answer your question, you can simply put your existing code inside a WHILE loop that checks

```
 WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Status IS NULL)
```

Your code will keep getting batches of 500 rows at a time until there are no more rows in Table1 with a NULL for Status.